# How to properly secure my Magento 2 site?

Tags: magento2, admin, security

I have my Mage2 site set up on an EC2 and use ssl access, plus a custom admin url and the permissions are all correct. However, I want to add .htaccess to my admin. What file do I need to add this too? The root .htaccess? And can I use order deny,allow or is there a better way? What other things should I be focused on (I have added captcha to admin and forced password change) to increase security?

Answer (score 0):

There is some information here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/secy/secy.html